# Database export to xls file when click on button in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, xls

I am Preparing one application.In my application contains database(SQlite) . My Database
My database contains 14 columns table and data.I want export that data into xls file when click on one button.Is it possible.Please guide me and provide some tutorials .

Comment: you can use opencsv library to convert your sqlite database to .csv or .xls file...search google for that library and some examples..

Comment: Thank u so much for grate suggestion.I have use opencsv it is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use opencsv library to convert your sqlite database to .csv or .xls file...search google for that library and some examples..

Comment: @MAC please vote my answer...if you think this is the helpful to others..Thank you..

Comment: It is working fine open office but when i open the file in ms xl it is showing "the file you are trying to open 'feedback.xls' is in different format than specified by the file extension. verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file.do u want to open the file now"

Comment: opened file in ms xls also but not taking shell it is taking "," separator.How to over come this.

Answer (score 0):

this way you can set the shell wise data in your xml file..

```
File dbFile=getDatabasePath("yourdatabase.sqlite");
     File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/XLS", "");
    if (!exportDir.exists())
                {
                    Log.d("export", ""+exportDir);

                    exportDir.mkdirs();

                }

                File file = new File(exportDir, "Your file.xls");
    db=dba.openDataBase();
                    file.createNewFile();
    CSVWriter csvWrite8 = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file8)); 
    Cursor curCSV8=db.rawQuery("Select * from tablename",null); 
    if(curCSV.moveToFirst())
                    {
                        curCSV.moveToFirst();

                        Log.d("log is","No of Column is ---->>>"+curCSV.getColumnNames().length);

                       do 
                        {
                            String arrStr[] ={curCSV.getString(0),curCSV.getString(1),curCSV.getString(2),curCSV.getString(3),curCSV.getString(4),curCSV.getString(5),curCSV.getString(6),curCSV.getString(7),curCSV.getString(8),curCSV.getString(9),curCSV.getString(10),curCSV.getString(11),curCSV.getString(12),curCSV.getString(13),curCSV.getString(14),curCSV.getString(15),curCSV.getString(16),curCSV.getString(17),curCSV.getString(18),curCSV.getString(19),curCSV.getString(20),curCSV.getString(21),curCSV.getString(22),curCSV.getString(23),curCSV.getString(25),curCSV.getString(26),curCSV.getString(27),curCSV.getString(28),curCSV.getString(29)};

                            csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);


                        }while(curCSV.moveToNext());
                    }
                    csvWrite.close();
```

Comment: @Chiru see this answer...hope this helps

Comment: it is working fine .File is open correct only in open office.but in micro soft excel open,but in rough format.

Answer (score -1):

My solution is to convert the sqlite database into csv in first step then in second step is to convert the csv file to xls and it works fine for me, you will need 2 libraries (opencsv-1.7.jar; poi-3.8-20120326.jar)

```
    public class ExportDatabaseCSVTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>

{

    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(DatabaseExampleActivity.this);

     @Override

    protected void onPreExecute()

    {

        this.dialog.setMessage("Exporting database...");

        this.dialog.show();

    }



    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args)

    {


        File dbFile=getDatabasePath("database_name");
        //AABDatabaseManager dbhelper = new AABDatabaseManager(getApplicationContext());
        AABDatabaseManager dbhelper = new AABDatabaseManager(DatabaseExampleActivity.this) ;
        System.out.println(dbFile);  // displays the data base path in your logcat 


        File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "");        

        if (!exportDir.exists()) 

        {
            exportDir.mkdirs();
        }


        File file = new File(exportDir, "excerDB.csv");


        try

        {

            if (file.createNewFile()){
                System.out.println("File is created!");
                System.out.println("myfile.csv "+file.getAbsolutePath());
              }else{
                System.out.println("File already exists.");
              }

            CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
          //SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();

            Cursor curCSV=db.getdb().rawQuery("select * from " + db.TABLE_NAME,null);

            csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());

            while(curCSV.moveToNext())

            {

                String arrStr[] ={curCSV.getString(0),curCSV.getString(1),curCSV.getString(2)};

             /*curCSV.getString(3),curCSV.getString(4)};*/

                csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);


            }

            csvWrite.close();
            curCSV.close();
            /*String data="";
            data=readSavedData();
            data= data.replace(",", ";");
            writeData(data);*/

            return true;

        }

        catch(SQLException sqlEx)

        {

            Log.e("MainActivity", sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);

            return false;

        }

        catch (IOException e)

        {

            Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(), e);

            return false;

        }

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success)

    {

        if (this.dialog.isShowing())

        {

            this.dialog.dismiss();

        }

        if (success)

        {

            Toast.makeText(DatabaseExampleActivity.this, "Export succeed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        else

        {

            Toast.makeText(DatabaseExampleActivity.this, "Export failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
}
```

Export CSV to XLS part

```
    public class CSVToExcelConverter extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {


    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(DatabaseExampleActivity.this);

    @Override
   protected void onPreExecute()

   {

       this.dialog.setMessage("Exporting to excel...");

       this.dialog.show();

   }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        ArrayList arList=null;
        ArrayList al=null;

        //File dbFile= new File(getDatabasePath("database_name").toString());
        File dbFile=getDatabasePath("database_name");
        String yes= dbFile.getAbsolutePath();

        String inFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/excerDB.csv";
        outFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/test.xls";
        String thisLine;
        int count=0;

        try {

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inFilePath);
        DataInputStream myInput = new DataInputStream(fis);
        int i=0;
        arList = new ArrayList();
        while ((thisLine = myInput.readLine()) != null)
        {
        al = new ArrayList();
        String strar[] = thisLine.split(",");
        for(int j=0;j<strar.length;j++)
        {
        al.add(strar[j]);
        }
        arList.add(al);
        System.out.println();
        i++;
        }} catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("shit");
        }

        try
        {
        HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = hwb.createSheet("new sheet");
        for(int k=0;k<arList.size();k++)
        {
        ArrayList ardata = (ArrayList)arList.get(k);
        HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) 0+k);
        for(int p=0;p<ardata.size();p++)
        {
        HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) p);
        String data = ardata.get(p).toString();
        if(data.startsWith("=")){
        cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        data=data.replaceAll("\"", "");
        data=data.replaceAll("=", "");
        cell.setCellValue(data);
        }else if(data.startsWith("\"")){
        data=data.replaceAll("\"", "");
        cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        cell.setCellValue(data);
        }else{
        data=data.replaceAll("\"", "");
        cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
        cell.setCellValue(data);
        }
        //*/
        // cell.setCellValue(ardata.get(p).toString());
        }
        System.out.println();
        }
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(outFilePath);
        hwb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
        System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated");
        } catch ( Exception ex ) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        } //main method ends
        return true;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success)

    {

        if (this.dialog.isShowing())

        {

            this.dialog.dismiss();

        }

        if (success)

        {

            Toast.makeText(DatabaseExampleActivity.this, "file is built!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        else

        {

            Toast.makeText(DatabaseExampleActivity.this, "file fail to build", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }


    }
```